# Displaying text whenever the date is changed from DatePicker

Tags: java, android, datepicker

Please have a look at the following code

**activity_main.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >

    <Button 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/btnText"
        />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/heading"
        />

    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />

    <DatePicker
        android:id="@+id/date"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.datepicker;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.DatePicker;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        DatePicker dp = (DatePicker)findViewById(R.id.date);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    private class DatePickerMe implements OnDateSetListener
    {

        public void onDateSet(DatePicker arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) 
        {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Click", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);

        }

    }
}
```

Here, I want to display the "Toast" message whenever the date is changed. I have attempted it under "DatePickerMe" inner class. But however, I don't know how to register this "OnDateSetListener" to date picker (I assumed onDateSetListener is the correct interface). Please help me to display the text, whenever the date is changed.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed a few things:

- You need to use [`DatePicker#init()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/DatePicker.html#init%28int,%20int,%20int,%20android.widget.DatePicker.OnDateChangedListener%29) to set your OnDateChangedListener.
- Also you **must** call `show()` on your Toast, otherwise it will never display.
- Last you don't *need* to extend the OnDateChangeListener class, you can just use it like below.

Try this:

```
OnDateChangedListener listener = new OnDateChangedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDateChanged(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
        // Show your Toast by calling show()!
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Click", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
};
DatePicker dp = (DatePicker)findViewById(R.id.date);

// Use Calendar to set the date to now
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
dp.init(calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR), calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH), calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH), listener);
```

Answer (score 1):

You register the listener when you call the init method.

```
dp.init( year, month, day, new DatePickerMe() );
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply..I really appreciate it :) +1